# SQL Resource Governor without master database permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, resource-governor

We have a production SQL database on amazon cloud and we don't have any write permissions in the master database.

In order to create a Resource Pool for resource governor, we need to create a classifier function in the master database to get details for the user sessions. So, due to the permission denies, we can't create a function in the master database.

Is there any other way to create a resource pool without having permissions in the master database ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have really NO permission, so defiantly can not create any object in master database.